# Two versions of libstdc++ in one process

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, std

In order to be compatible with older GNU/Linux distribution we consider linking our framework with a specific version of `libstdc++` and distributing it along with the binaries of our framework. The framework is written in C++ but offers only a C-API. The released framework would look like this:

```
$ ls
framework.h  libframework.so  libstdc++.so.6.0.24
$ readelf -d libframework.so
...
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)  Shared Library: [libstdc++.so.6.0.24]
...
0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH) Library runpath: [$ORIGIN]
...
```

This way a client of the framework can use an own and potentially different version of libstdc++, e.g.

```
$ ls
client  client.cpp  framework.h  libframework.so  libstdc++.so.6.0.24
$ readelf -d client
...
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)  Shared library: [libframework.so]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)  Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
...
0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH) Library runpath: [$ORIGIN]
...
$ ldd client
    libframework.so => /home/phlipsy/client/./libframework.so
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
    ...
    libstdc++.so.6.0.24 => /home/phlipsy/client/./libstdc++.so.6.0.24
    ...
```

Using `LD_DEBUG=bindings` on a system with significant older `libstdc++`, I got the expected behavior: The vast majority of C++ symbols is resolved by the system's `libstdc++.so.6`. Only those symbols needed by `libframework.so` which are not available in `libstdc++.so.6` come from `libstdc++.so.6.0.24`. Thanks to symbol versioning it is possible to distinguish the symbols from those two standard libraries.

On the other hand, if the present `libstdc++.so.6` is even newer than the distributed `libstdc++.so.6.0.24`, simply every symbol will be resolved by the system `libstdc++.so.6`.

**Question:** Does this approach have some huge drawback I didn't see yet? Possible candidates are:

- Incompatible ABIs between the system's `libstdc++.so.6` and the distributed `libstdc++.6.0.24`
- Wrong or incomplete symbol versioning
- Inconsistent internal library state if only a subset of functions is used

**Update I: Multiple binaries for different distibutions**: The framework is already cross platform which means we already have 32 bit and 64 bit binaries each for Windows, macOS and GNU/Linux. I'd really like to keep the number of necessary GNU/Linux binaries low since we have to build, test and deploy them all. Besides: We're really keen on those new and shiny C++11 features. This simple won't work as long as we support those old distributions.

**Update II: Linking `libstdc++` statically.** Unfortunately this approach has some serious downsides itself:

- The framework uses  `dlopen()` extensively in order to load plugins at runtime. Thus statically linking `libstdc++` to the framework also means linking every plugin statically to `libstdc++`. Otherwise the framework has to publish every symbol used by its plugins.
- There're symbols with default visibility inside `libstdc++.a` and, even worse, they aren't versioned. This means in any case the framework publishes symbols which in turn are used be the client even though they're from the wrong version of the standard library.
- Memory Leaks: There's a pool object inside `libstdc++` holding memory for thrown exceptions. This pool isn't freed since the developer of `libstdc++` assume its lifetime to be the same as the overall process.
- Throwing and catching exception between framework and plugins: This might be a non-issue with modern versions of `libstdc++` and `libgcc_s` but I suspect there're still some nasty details to it.

Comment: Can you build multiple binaries, one for each OS version you want to support?

Comment: I think it'd be much safer to statically link your version of libstdc++ then you will always know exactly which version you are using.

Comment: Have you succeed with the upper approach you described?